# Internet Explorer 9 beta - few float:right blocks inside float:right container are not at the same line

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

I have few float:right blocks inside float:right container (no width specified).

In the Internet Explorer 9b they are not at the same line. All other browsers (including IE8 and earlier) are displaying my blocks in one line.

How to handle this problem in the IE9? (without specifying fixed container width, if possible)

Comment: some code and a screenshot would be handy.

Comment: While I know they aren't different, do you have the same issue with IE9 Platform Preview 7? http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/info/downloads/Default.html

Comment: @JamesEggers That's a good suggestion.  IE9 Beta breaks my personal site, which I suspect is a similar problem to this.  However, in Platform Preview 7 is works great like it did in IE8 and previous versions.

Comment: Are your inside float:right blocks set to display:block? If not white space between tags can cause floated elements to shift down.

Comment: It does appear to be a bug, but only without the parent container width set.

Answer (score 2):

Without setting a width, the results are not predictable. 
See http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction.htm